# Invalid JSON Response in Datatable Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatable

I need an expert to fix this . This is my controller that load JSON .

```
foreach ($result->result() as $row){
    $customer = $row->customer_name;
    $ipull = $row->ip;
    if ($this->mikrotikext->mikrotik_connect($ip,$username,$password,$port) == true){
        $PING = $this->routerosapi->comm("/ping", array(
            "address" => $ipull,
            "count" => "2"
        ));
        if( $PING['0']['packet-loss'] == 0){
            $status = "Online";
        } else {
            $status = "Offline";
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('Connect_False','Failed To get');
        redirect('tmikrotik/router_list');
    }
    $data = array(
        'customer' => $customer,
        'address' => $ipull,
        'status' => $status
    );
    print json_encode($data);
}
```

And this is JSON response:

```
{"customer":"Trakindo Utama","address":"192.168.1.3","status":"Online"}{"customer":"Adira Finance","address":"192.168.1.10","status":"Offline"}{"customer":"Mandala Finance","address":"192.168.1.50","status":"Online"}
```

The problem is, when I load it into my data table, show popup invalid JSON response. This is my jQuery code

```js
$(function () {
    var table = $("#cpe-status").DataTable({
        fixedColumns: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "paging": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "./cpe",
            type: "GET",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        "scrollX": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"data": "customer", "title": "Host"},
            {"data": "address", "title": "Customer Name"},
            {"data": "status", "title": "Registered"}
            // {"data": "status", "title": "Status"}
        ]
    });
    // setInterval(function () {
    //     table.ajax.reload();
    // }, 10000);
})
```

Comment: This is definitely invalid JSON. There should be commas between the returned JSON objects, and the whole thing should probably be an array. You should check what `json_encode` does specifically.

Comment: thanks for response, so what i've to do ? i need solution not explanation. I'm just a newbie :)

Comment: @EdoVV Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing each result inside the loop. You should print the result as 1 array.

```
/* ============= Declare the data outside the loop ============= */
$data = array(); 

foreach ($result->result() as $row){
    $customer = $row->customer_name;
    $ipull = $row->ip;
    if ($this->mikrotikext->mikrotik_connect($ip,$username,$password,$port) == true) {
      $PING = $this->routerosapi->comm("/ping", array(
        "address" => $ipull,
        "count" => "2"
      ));
      if( $PING['0']['packet-loss'] == 0){
        $status = "Online";
      } else {
         $status = "Offline";
      }
    } else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('Connect_False','Failed To get');
      redirect('tmikrotik/router_list');
    }

    /* ============= Push each result on an array ============= */
    $data[] = array(
      'customer' => $customer,
      'address' => $ipull,
      'status' => $status
    );

  }


/* =============  print result (outside the loop ) ============= */
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: [{"customer":"Trakindo Utama","address":"192.168.1.3","status":"Online"}][{"customer":"Trakindo Utama","address":"192.168.1.3","status":"Online"},{"customer":"Adira Finance","address":"192.168.1.10","status":"Offline"}][{"customer":"Trakindo Utama","address":"192.168.1.3","status":"Online"},{"customer":"Adira Finance","address":"192.168.1.10","status":"Offline"},{"customer":"Mandala Finance","address":"192.168.1.50","status":"Online"}] ... The response show like that , still invalid json

Comment: Did you declare the `$data` outside the loop?

Comment: You should also print the `$data` outside the loop.

Comment: yes, i declared $data before looping , but the result same

Comment: Yes. Controller.